# Reading a model stored as binary

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science-model, aws

I'm using a s3 bucket to store a model I trained in python. Since I'm using an s3 bucket I convert the file to binary first and then store it on the bucket.

```
with open(r'model_svc_kernel_linear02.sav',"rb") as f:
    s3_client.upload_fileobj(f, bucket, "model.sav")
```

I'm able to read the file, however I can't use the model to predict since its only a bytes object.

```
model =  s3_resource.Object('mybucket', 'model.sav').get()['Body'].read()
```

When I try to read the binary file I get this error

```
with open(model) as f:
    contents = f.read()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I've been trying different encodings but none seem to be working. Is there a better way to store the model on the s3 bucket, read it and use it to make a prediction?

Answer (score 0):

To use the model stored in an **s3 bucket** for prediction, you can first load the model into memory by calling the `loads()` method of the **pickle** module, which ***converts the binary data into a Python object***. Then, you can use the loaded model to make predictions.

Here is an example of how to load the model and use it for prediction:

```py
import boto3
import pickle

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

# Download the model from the s3 bucket
response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket='mybucket', Key='model.sav')

# Read the binary data from the response
binary_data = response['Body'].read()

# Load the model from the binary data
model = pickle.loads(binary_data)

# Use the model for prediction
predictions = model.predict(X)
```